# How can I provide fixture yielded data to parametrization of a test function? If I can't, is there any alternatives?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing

I need to create multiple users (by sending HTTP requests) and run login page tests with created users data (login, password)

I have fixture, that generates users and provides their login data (list of tuples like [(login1, password1), (login2, password2)] in yield. I want to use this yield data as parametrization, because I know only one correct way to run 1 test multiple times with different test data.

Here's code:

**conftest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def test_user_fixture():
    print("INFO | Generating test user data")
    user_data_set = user_data_generator()
    login_data = []

    for user_data in user_data_set:
        login_data.append((user_data[0], user_data[1]))
        if send_user_create_request(user_data) != 200: # this function sends request to create user AND returns status_code
            pytest.exit("ERROR | Test user wasn't created")

    yield login_data

    print("INFO | Clearing test data")
```

**test_login_page.py**

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('webdriver_fixture', 'test_user_fixture')
class TestPositiveLogin:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("login, password", test_user_fixture)
    def test_positive_login(self, webdriver_fixture, login, password):
        driver = webdriver_fixture
        page = BasePage(driver)
        page.open_base_page()
        page.login(login, password)
```

Here I tried just using fuxture as parameters, because login_data perfectly fits into parameters data format, but python says

> NameError: name 'test_user_fixture' is not defined

Can you please help me solving this problem or maybe give another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `test_user_fixture` fixture returns a list of login/password. I am sure you are using `yield` because you want some clean up later (e.g. remove the users).

My proposal is for `test_user_fixture` to return just a single login/password. Then we can parametrize this fixture using the `params=` keyword:

```py
# conftest.py
import logging

import pytest

def user_data_generator():
    """Mocked"""
    return [
        ("user1", "password1"),
        ("user2", "password2"),
    ]

USERS_DATA = list(user_data_generator())

def test_id(user_data):
    """Given (login, password), return the login part.

    We use this login as part of the test ID
    """
    return user_data[0]


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True, params=USERS_DATA, ids=test_id)
def test_user_fixture(request):
    login, password = request.param[:2]
    logging.debug("In test_user_fixture, login=%r, password=%r", login, password)

    if send_user_create_request((login, password)) != 200:
        pytest.exit("ERROR | Test user wasn't created")
    yield login, password

    logging.info("Clearing test data")
```

and

```py
# test_login_page.py
import logging


class TestPositiveLogin:
    def test_positive_login(self, webdriver_fixture, test_user_fixture):
        login, password = test_user_fixture
        logging.debug("webdriver_fixture=%r", webdriver_fixture)
        logging.debug("login=%r", login)
        logging.debug("password=%r", password)
```

and

```ini
# pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
log_cli="true"
log_level="DEBUG"
```

Output when `log_cli="false"`:

```
test_login_page.py::TestPositiveLogin::test_positive_login[user1] PASSED
test_login_page.py::TestPositiveLogin::test_positive_login[user2] PASSED
```

Output when `log_cli="true"`:

```
test_login_page.py::TestPositiveLogin::test_positive_login[user1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------- live log setup ----------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG    root:conftest.py:26 In test_user_fixture, login='user1', password='password1'
---------------------------------------------------------------------- live log call -----------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG    root:test_login_page.py:8 webdriver_fixture='Mocked WebDriver'
DEBUG    root:test_login_page.py:9 login='user1'
DEBUG    root:test_login_page.py:10 password='password1'
PASSED
test_login_page.py::TestPositiveLogin::test_positive_login[user2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------- live log setup ----------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     root:conftest.py:32 Clearing test data for login='user1'
DEBUG    root:conftest.py:26 In test_user_fixture, login='user2', password='password2'
---------------------------------------------------------------------- live log call -----------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG    root:test_login_page.py:8 webdriver_fixture='Mocked WebDriver'
DEBUG    root:test_login_page.py:9 login='user2'
DEBUG    root:test_login_page.py:10 password='password2'
PASSED
-------------------------------------------------------------------- live log teardown ---------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     root:conftest.py:32 Clearing test data for login='user2'
```

Notes

- I assume that USERS_DATA contains `[(user, password, ...), ...]`
- The `params=USERS_DATA` parametrize the fixture. Even though this fixture is scoped at session level, it will be called once for each element in `USERS_DATA`. In other word, if `USERS_DATA` contains 2 elements, this fixture will be called twice.
- The `test_id()` function extracts the `login` from the test parameter, thus provide a better way to identify  the tests.
- The `test_user_fixture` returns a tuple of `(login, password)`, so in the test, we unpack it to make it easier:

  ```
    login, password = test_user_fixture
  ```
- I prefer to use `logging` over `print` because I can turn on/off via this line in `pyproject.toml`:

  ```
    log_cli="true"
  ```

  just replace `true` with `false` and I can effectively turn off all logging. I can also control the log level (e.g. WARN, INFO, DEBUG, ...) with this line:

  ```
    log_level="DEBUG"
  ```

## Update

If you remove the `ids=` part, then the output will look like this:

```
test_login_page.py::TestPositiveLogin::test_positive_login[test_user_fixture0] PASSED
test_login_page.py::TestPositiveLogin::test_positive_login[test_user_fixture1] PASSED
```

Notice the part inside the square brackets `test_user_fixture0` and `test_user_fixture1`: they are IDs which `pytest` generate automatically and they are not helpful.

What I want to place inside these square brackets are IDs which are useful such as the `login` name.

According to [pytest doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/8.0.x/reference/reference.html#pytest-fixture), the `ids=` could be a sequence of IDs. That means the following works the same way:

```py
USERS_DATA = list(user_data_generator())
TEST_IDS = [user_data[0] for user_data in USERS_DATA]
@pytest.fixture(
    scope="session",
    autouse=True,
    params=USERS_DATA,
    ids=TEST_IDS,
)
def test_user_fixture(request):
    ...
```

For example, if `USERS_DATA` is

```py
[
    ("user1", "password1"),
    ("user2", "password2"),
]
```

Then, `TEST_IDS` will be

```py
[
    "user1",
    "user2",
]
```

And these IDs will be used inside of the square brackets. Note that the `ids=` can also be a function which take in a single element of the `params=` parameter and return an ID. In this case we have:

```py
USERS_DATA = list(user_data_generator())
def test_id(user_data):
    # Example of user_data: ("user1", "password1")
    return user_data[0]

@pytest.fixture(
    scope="session",
    autouse=True,
    params=USERS_DATA,
    ids=test_id,
)
def test_user_fixture(request):
    ...
```

That means `pytest` will pass each element in `USERS_DATA` into the function `test_id` and use the return value as the ID.

Which method should we use? I believe the first method with `TEST_IDS` are easier to understand. The second method is more powerful and that is what I use in my projects.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. Can you please explain a little bit more about def test_id and ids=test_id?

Comment: Thanks again! IDs are really usefull to track down errors. Your whole solution worked for me too